# How can I use PHP to take raw POST data and save to a file?

Tags: php, xml, http, post, siri-xml

I'm working with an interface standard for exchanging information about the planned, current or projected performance of real-time public transport operations between different computer systems. [This standard is called SIRI](http://www.kizoom.com/standards/siri/).

To cut a long story short, I've made a subscription with a service that sends me XML data through this interface every 30 seconds. From what I've highlighted in the red box below, it states that HTTP is used to send this data which is what I would have preferred.

I need to create a PHP file that can listen for this HTTP data and then save it to a file (overwriting the previous file every 30 seconds).

I've done some preliminary research into how I can go about doing this and I've done a little reading on:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

and

```
php://input
```

How can I come up with a PHP solution for doing this with one of these methods or a better one?

[image]

Comment: you should just be able to do call `file_put_contents("outputfile.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: @Orangepill Wow is it really that easy lol? Ok that's great thanks. I need some sort of listener though, this data is going to be coming in every 30 seconds. Should I put it in some sort of loop to pull the contents from php://input every 30 seconds? Thanks

Comment: if its an http request coming in then apache will be your listener...

Comment: @Orangepill Ok, but the data is being posted via http every 30 seconds (like a heartbeat thing), does this mean I should call file_get_contents("php://input") every 30 seconds to get the new data? Thanks

Comment: No. They send the request to your server as a request. Apache catches the request and hands it off to php passing in the post body. You do the save and php shuts down. ~30 seconds later They send the request to your server ..... lather rinse repeat

Comment: X-Ref: [PHP listen for incoming XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554139/php-listen-for-incoming-xml)

Comment: @hakre I defined the third party and provided more detail/a specific problem. :)

Comment: Well I've seen that however it didn't get much more specific (also you *should* edit your earlier question and ask to get it re-opened). What have you tried so far? What didn't work with it? How should it look like when it works? Turn this into a programming question otherwise it's guessing. PHP normally works as announced.

Comment: @Orangepill solution just worked perfectly so thanks very much! Sorry if my question wasn't specific enough, I've been dying to get this working for days and at last I know how. >:D Thanks

Comment: Not a problem... I posted what I had so we can get the question closed.

Comment: @JoelKidd: No problem, like I wrote you yesterday, php://input normally works. It wasn't clear to me you didn't know how to read from it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All that really needs to be done is:

```
file_put_contents("outputfile.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Apache will deal with managing the incoming requests.

Comment: What about mine type? Fot example I have png file content I put it using file_put_contents, but later on when Im using \File->getMimeType() Im getting application/octet-stream  instead of image/png?